# GUI submit button not working- Java

Tags: java

I can get the `clear` and `exit` to work just fine, but for the life of my can't figure out why `submit` doesn't work and the results won't show up. It's probably something obvious I'm missing.  I had it working earlier but must have messed with something.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;



  public class ApplicationPanel extends JPanel 

{


private JLabel headLabel, firstLabel, lastLabel, addressLabel,    emailLabel, gpaLabel, gmatLabel;
    private JTextField firstname, lastname, addressbox, email, GPA, Gmat;
    private JTextArea results;
    private JButton submit, clear, exit; 


     public ApplicationPanel()
    {
    headLabel = new JLabel ("Catskill College Application");
    firstLabel = new JLabel ("Enter your first name: ");
    lastLabel = new JLabel ("Enter your last name");
    addressLabel = new JLabel ("Enter your address: ");
    emailLabel = new JLabel ("Enter your email: ");
    gpaLabel = new JLabel ("Enter your GPA: ");
    gmatLabel = new JLabel ("Select your GMAT score: ");

    results = new JTextArea(7, 30);

    firstname = new JTextField (12); 
    lastname = new JTextField (12); 
    addressbox = new JTextField (20);
    email = new JTextField (20); 
    GPA = new JTextField (5); 
    Gmat = new JTextField (5);

    submit = new JButton ("SUBMIT");
    clear = new JButton ("CLEAR"); 
    exit = new JButton ("EXIT");

    ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
    submit.addActionListener (listener);
    clear.addActionListener (listener);
    exit.addActionListener (listener);

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    constraints.gridwidth = 2;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.insets = new Insets (5, 5, 20, 5); 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    add (headLabel, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.insets = new Insets (5, 5, 5, 5); 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    add (firstLabel, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.insets = new Insets (5, 5, 5, 5); 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    add (firstname, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.insets = new Insets (5, 5, 5, 5); 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    add (lastLabel, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.insets = new Insets (5, 5, 5, 5); 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;     
    add (lastname, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 3;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.insets = new Insets (5, 5, 5, 5); 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    add (addressLabel, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 3;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.insets = new Insets (5, 5, 5, 5); 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;     
    add (addressbox, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 4;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.insets = new Insets (5, 5, 5, 5); 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    add (emailLabel, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 4;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.insets = new Insets (5, 5, 5, 5); 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;     
    add (email, constraints);



    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 5;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.insets = new Insets (5, 5, 5, 5); 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    add (gpaLabel, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 5;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.insets = new Insets (5, 5, 5, 5); 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;     
    add (GPA, constraints);


    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 6;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.insets = new Insets (5, 5, 5, 5); 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    add (gmatLabel, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 6;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.insets = new Insets (5, 5, 5, 5); 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;     
    add (Gmat, constraints);



    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 8;
    constraints.gridwidth = 2;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.insets = new Insets (25, 85, 5, 5); 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    add (submit, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 8;
    constraints.gridwidth = 2;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.insets = new Insets (25, 225, 5, 5); 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    add (clear, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 8;
    constraints.gridwidth = 2;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.insets = new Insets (25, 355, 5, 5); 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    add (exit, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 9;
    constraints.gridwidth = 2;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.insets = new Insets (5, 5, 5, 5); 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    add (results, constraints);

    setPreferredSize (new Dimension(700, 500));
    setBackground (Color.GRAY);
}



private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getSource() == submit)

            if (firstname.getText().length() == 0) 

            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(submit,"You didn't enter your name!!", "Message", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                firstname.requestFocus();
                firstname.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            }
            else if (lastname.getText().length() == 0) 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(submit,"You didn't enter your address!!", "Message", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                lastname.requestFocus();
                lastname.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            }   

            else 
            {

                String Acceptance, name1;

                if ((Integer.parseInt(GPA.getText()) >2.99) && (Integer.parseInt(Gmat.getText()) > 400) )
                {
                    Acceptance = "Unconditional Acceptance";
                    name1 = firstname.getText()+ lastname.getText();
                }

                else if  ((Integer.parseInt(GPA.getText()) > 2.49 ) && (Integer.parseInt(Gmat.getText()) > 350) )
                {
                    Acceptance = "Conditional Acceptance";
                    name1 = firstname.getText()+ lastname.getText();

                }

                else 
                {
                    Acceptance = "Application Rejected";
                    name1 = firstname.getText()+ lastname.getText();
                }


                results.setText("Name : " + name1 + "\n" + "Address: " + addressbox.getText() + "\n" + "Application Status: " + Acceptance);
            }

                if (event.getSource() == clear)
                {
                    firstname.setText("");
                    lastname.setText("");
                    addressbox.setText("");
                    email.setText("");
                    GPA.setText("");
                    Gmat.setText("");



                }

                if (event.getSource() == exit)
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }


}
}
```

Here's what the console reads:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For     input string: "3.95"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at  ApplicationPanel$ButtonListener.actionPerformed(ApplicationPanel.java:231)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: what output doyou get? please update your question.

Comment: *"3.95"* is obviously not an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing it from Int to Double fixed it (duh) thanks!